# Image not visible on array mapping

Tags: image, react-native

I am following this approach for storing images in my program:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)


        const status_image = [
            {
                image: require('../../assets/claimsImages/7.png')
            },
            {
                image: require('../../assets/claimsImages/4.png')
            },
            {
                image: require('../../assets/claimsImages/2.png')
            },
            {
                image: require('../../assets/claimsImages/question.png')
            }
        ]
        this.state = {
            newdata: [],
            images: status_image
        }
    }
```

I need to map these images as:

```
render(){
var img = this.state.images.image.map( a );
        console.log(img);
return(

   <View> <Image source={img} /> </View>
)
```

}

But it consoles error `undefined`.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you can generate a method and render whenever you want.

```
_renderImage(image_index){

        let imageUrl = '../../assets/claimsImages/'+image_index+'.png'

        return (
            <Image   
                resizeMode={'contain'}  
                style={{flex:1, width:50, height:50}}
                source={require(imageUrl)}/>
        )
}
```

And you can use like :

```
this._renderImage(1)
```

Comment: Can I use this `let imageUrl = '../../assets/claimsImages/'+image_index+'.png'` in similar way for generating array of images?

Comment: In you array you just need to store image index